# how to use name from sys.Table in T-sql to reseed the identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This's my code for reseed all my tables

```
begin 
    declare @tableName nvarchar(max);
    declare c cursor for 
    select name from sys.tables;
    open c ;
    fetch next from c into  @tableName ;
    while (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
    begin 
            DBCC CHECKIDENT  (@tableName,reseed,0); 
            print @tableName;
            fetch next from c into  @tableName ;        
    end
    close c; 
    deallocate c;
end
```

so the error is

```
Cannot find a table or object with the name "ր翼.㻐槺.욢ै..Ճ...". Check the system catalog.
```

who i can execute it and why i see this error 
and thanks
[image: this the capture of screen]

Comment: `CheckIdent` takes a table name, not an expression, as an argument. It will require _dynamic SQL_ to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following statement as a base - change it as you need. In the current implementation we have `PRINT` and we are generating the command only for tables having identity column:

```
DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @DynamicTSQLStatement = STUFF
(
     (
         SELECT ';' + 'DBCC CHECKIDENT  (''' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(T.[schema_id])) + '.' + QUOTENAME(T.[name]) + ''',reseed,0); PRINT ''' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(T.[schema_id])) + '.' + QUOTENAME(T.[name]) + ''''
         FROM [sys].[tables] T
         INNER JOIN [sys].[columns] C
            ON T.[object_id] = C.[object_id]
         WHERE C.[is_identity] = 1
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
     ,1
     ,1
     ,''
);

SELECT @DynamicTSQLStatement;
```